# MS Access tables analysis

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have in my database 4 tables (years 2014,2013,2012,2011) and each of them have same column CODE. I would like to create a new table like this :

[TABLE IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Dwfx.png)

where 
**codes** is: all unique codes in all four tables 
and **year 2014**: how many times is for example code 6602658 in this table ?

Thanks for any advice :-)

Comment: I can't see your picture, and I think I might have answered this incorrectly.  What are the headers and results you are looking for in your table?

Comment: Is it woking now?:) http://oi57.tinypic.com/161xjde.jpg

Comment: I'm at work all of these sites are blocked, I should have been clearer in my last comment.

Comment: the result table should have 4 columns (code, year 2011, year 2012, year 2013, year 2014). In column code is all unique codes from all tables. In column year 2011 is how many times is code in table Year2011. In column year 2012 is how many times is code in table Year2012.

Comment: In one table can be one code many times. so the result is: code (575674) is in the table 2011 (5X) in 2012 (2X) in 2013 (8X) in 2014 (1X) and i want to do this for all unique codes in all tables ..is that possible?

Comment: See edited answer.  That should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new query and put this in as the SQL:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 2014 As Year, tblCombined.Code 
 INTO tblNEWTABLE 
 FROM (SELECT Code FROM tbl2014 
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT Code FROM tbl2013 
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT Code FROM tbl2012 
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT Code FROM tbl2011) As tblCombined
```

where "Code" is the name of the field and "tbl2014" etc are the names of the tables.

You may be looking for this:

```
 SELECT tblCombined.Code, Sum(tblCombined.C2014) As Count2014
        , Sum(tblCombined.C2013) As Count2013
        , Sum(tblCombined.C2012) As Count2012
        , Sum(tblCombined.C2011) As Count2011
 INTO tblNEWTABLE 
 FROM (SELECT Code, Count(Code) As C2014, 0 As C2013, 0 As C2012, 0 As C2011
       FROM tbl2014 GROUP BY Code
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT Code, 0 As C2014, Count(Code) As C2013, 0 As C2012, 0 As C2011
       FROM tbl2013 GROUP BY Code           
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT Code, 0 As C2014, 0 As C2013, Count(Code) As C2012, 0 As C2011
       FROM tbl2012 GROUP BY Code
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT Code, 0 As C2014, 0 As C2013, 0 As C2012, Count(Code) As C2011
       FROM tbl2011 GROUP BY Code
      ) As tblCombined 
GROUP BY tblCombined.Code
```

This should give you the count of records having each code for each year.
This is likely not the most efficient way to do this, but it should work.

You could also use a "CROSSTAB" query, but this solution will work too.

Comment: thank you very much, you really help me a lot ! :-) if you have time can you please help me.. if i dont want to search by all Code characters, but only firts 8 charakters.. for example original Code is 1234A12345, but in results table is counted Codes with same first characters 1234A123

Comment: Use the Left() function on the field.  So for instance, SELECT Left(Code, 8) As Code, Count(Left(Code, 8)) As c2014 ..... FROM tbl2014 GROUP BY Left(Code, 8)...

Comment: Also, please mark this as the answer if it answers your question.